# How to link 2 values of a list in Python

Tags: python-3.x

my problem is that I have a list which contains sublists like this

> list = [["a", 2]["b", 4]["a", 5]["c", 8]]

and I have to sum the values in the position 1 of the sublists that have the same character, so the final list should be like this

> final_list = [["a", 7]["b", 4]["c", 8]]

but I can't find a way to do it, if someone knows how to make that I would be really grateful, thanks

I have tried this to find the equals but with it I don't know which ones there are and thus I cannot sum the numbers associated with them

```
> def process(list):
>     for i in range(len(list)-1):
>         for j in range(i+1, len(list)):
>             if list[i][0] == list[j][0]:  
>                 print("there are equals")
>             else:
>                 print("there are no equals")
```

Comment: Are you creating the original list? If so, I'd suggest instead using a `dict` with the letters as keys and a list of numbers as values. For example, `{"a": [2,5], "b": [4], "c": [8]}`. You could then create `final_list` out of that dictionary.

Comment: @gmdev yes, the original list is created by the user and the user can always add new elements. I am a real noob and my course is very basic so we aren't allowed to use dictionaries, only lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use a dictionary:

```
def process(lst):
    final_list = []
    for ltr,number in lst:
        for existing in final_list:
            if existing[0] == ltr:
                existing[1] += number
                break
        else:
            final_list.append([ltr, number])
    return final_list
```

It checks if the letter is in `final_list`. If it is, it adds the number to the previous value. If it is not, it appends the letter and number to `final_list`.

With a dictionary:

```
def process(lst):
    dct = {}
    for letter,number in lst:
        dct[letter] = dct.get(letter, 0) + number
    return [[k,v] for k,v in dct.items()]
```

With `itertools.groupby` and sorting the list:

```
from itertools import groupby

def process(lst):
    return [[a, sum(x[1] for x in b)] for a,b in groupby(sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[0]), key=lambda x: x[0])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another one and benchmarks:

```
def process(lst):
    ctr = defaultdict(int)
    for letter, number in lst:
        ctr[letter] += number
    return [*map(list, ctr.items())]
```

Benchmark with a million sublists of random lowercase letters and random numbers from 1 to 10:

```
 135.2 ±  0.4 ms  Kelly_defaultdict
 174.2 ±  0.5 ms  _001_dict
 227.8 ±  0.4 ms  Samiulhaq_Chardiwall
 633.6 ±  1.2 ms  _001_groupby
1095.5 ±  1.6 ms  _001_first
2250.4 ±  9.3 ms  Vincent_Bénet_numpy

Python: 3.10.8 (main, Oct 11 2022, 11:35:05) [GCC 11.3.0]
NumPy:  1.23.5
```

Benchmark code:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
import random
import numpy
from itertools import groupby
from timeit import timeit
from statistics import mean, stdev
from collections import defaultdict
import gc, sys

def Kelly_defaultdict(lst):
    ctr = defaultdict(int)
    for letter, number in lst:
        ctr[letter] += number
    return [*map(list, ctr.items())]

def _001_first(lst):
    final_list = []
    for ltr,number in lst:
        for existing in final_list:
            if existing[0] == ltr:
                existing[1] += number
                break
        else:
            final_list.append([ltr, number])
    return final_list

def _001_dict(lst):
    dct = {}
    for letter,number in lst:
        dct[letter] = dct.get(letter, 0) + number
    return [[k,v] for k,v in dct.items()]

def _001_groupby(lst):
    return [[a, sum(x[1] for x in b)] for a,b in groupby(sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[0]), key=lambda x: x[0])]

# invalid, produces tuples instead of lists
def darth_baba(lst):
    final_list = {}
    for i in lst:
        if i[0]  not in final_list:
            final_list[i[0]] = i[1]
        else:
            final_list[i[0]] += i[1]

    return list(zip(final_list.keys(), final_list.values()))

def Samiulhaq_Chardiwall(lst):
    dictionary = {} # 
    for sub_list in lst:
        dictionary[sub_list[0]] = dictionary.get(sub_list[0], 0) + sub_list[1]
    return [list(x) for x in dictionary.items()]

def Vincent_Bénet_numpy(lst):
    v1, v2 = numpy.array(lst).T
    return [[str(char), int(v2[v1==char].astype(numpy.int32).sum())] for char in numpy.unique(v1)]

funcs = _001_first, _001_dict, _001_groupby, Samiulhaq_Chardiwall, Vincent_Bénet_numpy, Kelly_defaultdict

lst = [["a", 2], ["b", 4], ["a", 5], ["c", 8]]

for f in funcs:
    print(f(lst), f.__name__)

times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e3 for t in sorted(times[f])[:10]]
    return f'{mean(ts):6.1f} ± {stdev(ts):4.1f} ms '

for i in range(100):
    n = 10**6
    lst = [[c, i] for c, i in zip(random.choices(ascii_lowercase, k=n), random.choices(range(1, 11), k=n))]
    for f in funcs:
        gc.collect()
        t = timeit(lambda: f(lst), number=1)
        times[f].append(t)

    if i > 1:
        print(i+1)
        for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
            print(stats(f), f.__name__)
        print()
        print('Python:', sys.version)
        print('NumPy: ', numpy.__version__)
```

Comment: Alternatively `return list(sum((Counter({k:v}) for k,v in ll), start=Counter()).items())` (or maybe `functools.reduce` is preferable to `sum` since it doesn't need an initialiser)

Comment: @Stef Is that an attempt to write the slowest possible solution? :-)

Comment: Mostly it's me being frustrated that `Counter` doesn't work the way I'd like on a list of pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a for loop and a dictionary as follows:

```
l = [["a", 2],["b", 4],["a", 5],["c", 8]]
final_list = {}
for i in l:
    if i[0]  not in final_list:
        final_list[i[0]] = i[1]
    else:
        final_list[i[0]] += i[1]

final_list = list(zip(final_list.keys(), final_list.values()))
```

This will output >> `[('a', 7), ('b', 4), ('c', 8)]`

Comment: Alternatively `for k,v in l: final_list[k] = final_list.get(k, 0) + v`

Answer (score 0):

**Here is what you can do:**

in my point of view **Dictionary** is the best solution. although you use searching mechanism but that will be ineffecient.

**Solution using dictionary**

```
lst = [["a", 2], ["b", 4], ["a", 5], ["c", 8]]
dictionary = {} # intializing empty dictionary


for sub_list in lst:
# The following line of code first check wheater the key exists or not using dictionary.get() method.
# if the the key already exists so the value will be retrieved and added to the new value.
# if not the new value will be added to 0
  dictionary[sub_list[0]] = dictionary.get(sub_list[0], 0) + sub_list[1]

print(dictionary.items()) # Outputs: [('a', 7), ('b', 4), ('c', 8)]

# if you want to convert the inside elements of the list to list use the following code:

new_list = [list(x) for x in dictionary.items()]
print(new_list) # Outputs: [['a', 7], ['b', 4], ['c', 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple way with numpy using a mask, ***very fast*** in case of huge lists, a ***little slower*** in case of small lists.

```
import numpy
v1, v2 = numpy.array([["a", 2],["b", 4],["a", 5],["c", 8]]).T
v2 = v2.astype(numpy.int32)
final_list = [[str(char), int(v2[v1==char].sum())] for char in numpy.unique(v1)]
```

Result:

```
>>> final_list = [['a', 7], ['b', 4], ['c', 8]]
```

Comment: Bold claim. Please show your benchmark (code and results).

Comment: Your result contains NumPy data types (numpy.str_ and numpy.int64 instead of str and int), so that's not the right output.

Comment: @KellyBundy types fixed in edit thx. For benchmark it is based on my experience with numpy, long to create numpy array but fast to make operation on.

Comment: *"long to create numpy array"* - Indeed. And that alone is already why I doubt the claim that this is very fast.

Comment: The numpy array is created only once, this is why it is faster for huge quantity of data, like t = a * n + b. (t=time, n=number of points). b is bigger for numpy while a is smaller

Comment: Well, see my benchmark with a million sublists, where your solution was over ***16 times slower*** than the fastest, and over twice as slow as the slowest other.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing corresponds to functions [reduceByKey in pyspark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.reduceByKey.html) and [map_reduce in more_itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.map_reduce).

```py
from more_itertools import map_reduce
from operator import itemgetter

def process(lst):
    return list(
        map_reduce(lst,
                   keyfunc=itemgetter(0),
                   valuefunc=itemgetter(1),
                   reducefunc=sum)
        .items()
    )
```